# Yowsup - Whatsapp Python Library

Tags: python, whatsapp, yowsup

I am absolutely new to Python and the Rasberry Pi. I had a look at the Yowsup library to be able to send a Whatsapp message with my Rasberry Pi.

By using yowsup-cli I can send a message etc.

My problem.... I dont understand the sample programs at all. From a .NET background I would think that one would create an Object and then perhaps do something like Object.SendMessage("Number", "Message")

The examples seems to be much more complicated. I truly dont understand. Have someone written a simple Python Script before doing what I want to do? Just as an example so that I understand more clearly? I have done a lot of reading. I guess I am stuck with .NET in my head.

Thank you!

Jaco

Comment: if you want there's also the .NET porting

Comment: Hi! I tried the .NET library but it doesn't authenticate! I am not sure which version to use and perhaps as with yowsup one should change the version number and key somewhere?

Comment: I'm sorry I've never used it .. but i saw there are some example in the repository

Comment: it loooks you can di everything like authenticate.. send to different numbers and so on

Comment: True. A bit of a struggle. Thank you anycase!

Comment: string nickname = "WhatsApiNet";
            string sender = "316******3"; // Mobile number with country code (but without + or 00)
            string password = "xLl***************GSA=";//v2 password
            string target = "316********6";// Mobile number to send the message to

            WhatsApp wa = new WhatsApp(sender, password, nickname, true);

Comment: You can.... I know that code but.... there is an exception when it is attempting to authenticate...

Comment: what it give to you? ..what the exception say?

Comment: I tried to reproduce the issue... no exception now, it hangs.